# Shell Script - Printing Tokens

Tags: string, shell, printing, token

Let's say a variable:

```
word="Hi there, how are you?"
```

How would I print it so that the output would be:

```
Hi
there,
how
are
you?
```

So far, I've only learn the grep, cut, find, tr commands

Answer (score 2):

Using bash:

```
word="Hi there, how are you?"
for i in $word; do echo $i; done
```

or, with `tr`:

```
echo $word | tr ' ' '\n'
```

Comment: Thank you. I prefer your first one.

Comment: With bash, you can use a here-string: `tr ' ' '\n' <<< "$word"`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $word|awk '{for(i=1;i<NF+1;i++) printf("%s\n", $i)}'
```

Also work well, please have a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf "%s\n" $word
```

the format specifier will be re-used until all tokens are consumed